# How to show a MovieClip randomly in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my game, I've three holes (MovieClips) and I want that every time (of 20 times) the rat (MovieClip) to be over one of those holes.

How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please further explain what you want to achieve, maybe with an example (can be a drawing). Can you also post what you have already tried? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on tips how to ask a good question.

Comment: @DeviMandasari I tried to reformulate your question to be more clear, hope that I did it correctly.

Comment: thanks for your correct GerritBertier . Thanks for your correct and you can reformulate my question to be more clear akmozo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. One solution could be to have an invisible rat graphic, and you make it visible every X seconds.

```
// the array has all the hole movieclips
var allHoles:Array = new Array('hole1_mc','hole2_mc', 'hole3_mc');

// show a rat 20 times every 2 seconds
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000,20); 
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showRat);
myTimer.start();

function showRat(e:Event):void{
    // choose a random hole
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    var randomHole = allHoles[rand];

    rat_mc.visible = true;
    rat_mc.x = randomHole.x;
    rat_mc.y = randomHole.y;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Kokodoko, i already to try it, but error. the output is ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property x not found on String and there is no default value.
 at cobaaaaa_fla::MainTimeline/showRat()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick(). 
What should I do?

Comment: There's a typo: the array should be: new Array(hole1_mc, hole2_mc, hole3_mc); instead of containing strings. You can download the FLA here: https://goo.gl/ch0mdQ

Comment: Wow... thank you so much @Kokodoko . This is helpful.

Comment: hy @Kokodoko i need you, i wanna ask you about code, can you give me your contact ?, thanks :)

Comment: @DeviMandasari I created a chat room called PrivateFlashChat you can find me there!